# access php cookie from same domain not working correctly

Tags: php, cookies, dns

I'm not great at PHP, and everything I currently know, I have just taught myself by browsing the internet.

I am currently trying to work with cookies in my page, in order to set up a persistent log in for a day.

Basically I have gotten as far as managing to set a cookie, with a value of the session username. This value is set when the user logs on.
So the user enters credentials, php checks against mysql database, if it is successful then the username is set as session variable, and this is then set as a cookie.

This works, as if I run this php and immediately echo the cookie, the username is displayed.

This is all done on my login form which is brought up in a tinybox (similar to a lightbox and other such pop up windows). The cookie and echo seems to work correctly from here.

However, when the login is successful, it refreshes the parent page, (root page of my site) and all seems well. However, if I then try to echo the cookie from the index page, I can not access it.

I know cookies have limitations on them for security, but seeing as how my login page, and my home page are on the same domain, then I thought this would have worked.

Is this something I am likely doing wrong, or is it a cookie limitation. Would it work if I set the cookie from the index page itself, rather than from within a tinybox?

If anyone wants examples of the code I am using, it can be provided.

Many thanks
Eds

Comment: Trying to roll you own cookie auth routine is a *bad* idea (especially as you say `I'm not great at PHP`) - I am not trying to discourage you from learning how to do this, but learn [by example](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+cookie+auth), not by starting from scratch. There will be many, many security issues that I am 99.99% sure you won't have thought of.

Comment: I must admit that most of the other things I have learnt have been using code examples from others, so don't know why I haven't looked for cookie examples. I generally try starting from scartach to start with so I can get a fairly good grasp on the basics, but in this case it is beyond me. Security isn't a huge issue, as this is only for an internal intranet, and the only reason I am doing logins are for preferences, rather than security. Would you suggest I just try to find some prebuilt routines to at least examine and work from? thanks for your advice!

Comment: there are plenty of pre-built routines out there (see above link for a good start) and I would indeed suggest you start by looking at them if that is what you want to do (continued in next comment)

Comment: ...but from what you describe as the purpose of this excercise, I would also suggest you consider using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) instead of setting your own cookies. If you do this, a) PHP handles all the cookie processing for you and b) you only need a single cookie to allow you to store as much data as you like about the session (within reason) - so you could store your permissions array in the session, and not have to query the database every time.

Comment: You would have to alter the cookie lifetime of the session though, because by default they are (unsurprisingly) session cookies, that are destroyed when the user closes the browser. However, this is easily overcome using the first argument of [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: I am using sessions at the moment to control user preferences based on a database, but was looking at cookies for the persistent log on as, like you said, sessions are only for that session. I did not realise you could alter the life time of a session. So by setting the sessions params, I could have a user log in, come back next day after closing their browser, and still be logged in? Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: In theory yes, although having just revisited this I now remember that the exact behaviour of PHP's session lifetime is not necessarily what you would expect - there are many factors to consider and it starts to get very complicated and not very portable in order to get it working how you describe. If you are truly not bothered about security with this, you should probably stick with your original approach (sorry about the bum info)

Comment: So, back to the original question - did you set the `$path` parameter for your cookie? I suspect this is likely to be the cause of the problem if you did. Please describe the location of the script that opens in the window, the location of the script that it's form is submitted to, the location of the script in your main page, and the line of code you used to set the cookie, and I'll see if I can work out what's going on.

Comment: if($rem == 'yes') {      $cookievalue = $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'];  setcookie("newcookie", $cookievalue, time()+60);  echo $_COOKIE["newcookie"];

Comment: bit hard to read in a comment box, but basically, the rem variable is a checkbox on my login form to say remember login, then the $cookievalue variable is my session username. so when setting the cookie, i set it with a name of newcookie, with the cookievalue, and a 60 second expiry. if i then echo the cookie straight away, its fine, if i copy the exat line of code to echo it, into the parent page, it fails. the parent is index.php, on the http://intranet/ domain. thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4572/discussion-between-daverandom-and-eds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was helped out by DaveRandom on this one.

Turns out I had to add "/" as the root path for the cookie, so that it was available to parent pages.

Answer (score 0):

Which navigator you use? Chrome can't work by default with local cookies. You can enable with  command line --enable-file-cookies

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3014

Comment: Im designing and testing using IE9, but most things seem to work as expected in chrome, firefox and safari.